# Mongo aggregation $match equality expression based upon a calculated value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to retrieve all the users who registered date is 2007. Something seems to be wrong with my syntax here. I don't know where to put the equality expression but this is giving the following error:

> MongoServerError: unknown top level operator: $year. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { $year: { $convert: { input: "$registered.date", to: "date" } } },
    },
    {$project:{_id:0, name:1}}
])
```

I know the `$convert` string to date code is working because I put it in a `$project` and it's working:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        year: { $year: { $convert: { input: "$registered.date", to: "date" } } }
      },
    },
  ]); --> printing out the correct years
```

How do I perform a restriction in the match clause with this `$year` value to restrict only for 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't start with the aggregation operator in the `$match` stage. You need the `$expr` in order to use the aggregation operator.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $eq: [
        {
          $year: {
            $convert: {
              input: "$registered.date",
              to: "date"
            }
          }
        },
        2007
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ga1JMRF5Bc1)

Note that the `$convert` operator can be simplified with `$toDate` operator.

```
$toDate: "$registered.date"
```